# $locationProvider stops other scripts to load and displays nothing in console.log

Tags: angularjs, routes, location-provider

I'm using `$locationProvider` as a dependency and used `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` on **routes.js** and used `<base href='/">` on **index.html** page but that turns out to be an error like **Error: $injector:modulerr**
**Module Error** and some weird stuff, so I have searched on it and removed the `<base href='/">` and modified `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});` , Now I don't face any errors but nothing is loaded like no views nor controllers or any, I'm using a lot of other cdn's. AnyOne please help me out...

**Edited**

If i need to share my code on **plunker** I have to edit all the files to point to correct location to access them as this app deals with directives, services and other stuff so giving below some code that gives u some view on what my problem was

Here's github repository link: https://github.com/avinashdv/GameOfThrones
please edit the $locationProvider on **routes.js** with the below code and index.html with the `<base href='/">` to see the error

Also trying the `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` on **routes.js** without `<base href='/">` on **index.js** also results nothing...

**routes.js**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl     : 'pages/main-view.html',
    controller      : 'firstController',
    controllerAs    : 'firstCtrl'
})
```

**index.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="/" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-
awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: post your code !

Comment: Could you please past codes to answer your question

Comment: @Maher Any solution for the problem??

Comment: @Sajeetharan Any solution for the above?